# import tkinter error

Tags: python, tkinter, build, exe, cx-freeze

[image: The Error I receive when I try to open the exe file.]

I have a .py file that I am trying to convert into an exe. I have tried numerous tries to build this file using `cx_Freeze`, but I keep getting the same error every time.

I've heard that it's got something to do with `cx_Freeze`, so I uninstalled `cx_Freeze` and reinstalled it using `pip install cx_freezexxxx.whl wheel`, but that still didn't work. I build my exe by writing `python setup.py build` in command line. Here's my setup .py code.

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys

import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\louisa\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\louisa\\tcl\\tk8.6"


base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("filemakergui.py", base=base, icon="Treetog-I-Documents.ico")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "ALT File Maker",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter"], "include_files":["Treetog-I-Documents.ico", "Hopstarter-Sleek-Xp-Basic-Help.ico", "Custom-Icon-Design-Flatastic-2-Success.ico"]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "ALT File Maker",
    executables = executables
)
```

Is there anything wrong with what I've written in my `setup.py` file? I've been stuck on this problem for several days now. Any tips on resolving an issue like this?

Comment: If you don't running python 3.6 you can try pyInstaller. It runs with Python 2.7, 3.3–3.5 with most modules (tkinter included) without any modifications.